# Get rid off extra TableViewCellSeparator when using custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building a custom table view cell with the Interface Builder. After creating a new view that inherits from UITableViewCell, I get the following `.xib`. Right down at the bottom of the view you can see the separator line.

[image: Custom Cell]

After running the app and jumping into the UI debugger, I see two separators for the cells that came out of the UITableViewDataSource methods.

[image]
[image]

Obviously this looks weird. Why the duplication? How do I get rid off it?

### Edit 1

Thanks to the suggestion by Shubhank, removing separators from the table view removed the duplicates.

[image]

Comment: try setting tableview separator to none and seeing where hiding views of cell one at a time to see where the shadow/separator is popping up

Comment: @Shubhank I think that solves it, I've included an update to my question. If you want to, please post an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: done, thanks. if you get a better answer, you can accept that if you wish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TableWrapperView might be having a custom selector or even the cell xib. Not sure here since i can't see the view details here.

A simple solution would be to just remove the source `UITableView` separators by setting them to none. That way you would have only one selector showing up